# Где собраны фундаментально накопленные знания по русской речи?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Какой источник является первоочередным, наиболее авторитетным с изложением правил русского языка. Фиксированная норма, фиксированное правило в каких местах содержатся? Как в этом источнике появляются новые данные, кем и как и на каком основании они вносятся, кто проводит редактуру? Связано ли утверждение зданий в сем источнике по этой науке с подобным же утверждением в других науках?

Comment: А для начала справочник Розенталя или Лопатина вас не устроит? Фундаментальность - она не сразу, она потом придет. Постепенно. Вы же физику не с квантовой механики начинали изучать? (Это, пардон, про "другие науки", они ведь в вашем вопросе тоже есть, правда, очень невнятно).

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая книга - ПРАВИЛА РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ.Полный академический справочник. Авторы: Валгина Н.С., Еськова Н.А., Иванова О.Е., Кузьмина С.М., Лопатин В.В., Челыдова Л.К. Ответственный редактор В. В. Лопатин

Предисловие

> Предлагаемый справочник подготовлен Институтом русского языка им. В.
>   В. Виноградова РАН и Орфографической комиссией при Отделении
>   историко-филологических наук Российской академии наук. Он является
>   результатом многолетней работы Орфографической комиссии, в состав
>   которой входят лингвисты, преподаватели вузов, методисты, учителя
>   средней школы. В работе комиссии, многократно обсуждавшей и одобрившей
>   текст справочника, приняли участие: канд. филол. наук Б. 3. Букчина,
>   канд. филол. наук, профессор Н. С. Валгина, учитель русского языка и
>   литературы С. В. Волков, доктор филол. наук, профессор В. п.
>   Григорьев, доктор пед. наук, профессор А. Д. Дейкина, канд. филол.
>   наук, доцент Е. В. Джанджакова, канд. филол. наук Н. А. Еськова,
>   академик РАН А. А. Зализняк, канд. филол. наук О. Е. Иванова, канд.
>   филол. наук О. Е. Кармакова, доктор филол. наук, профессор Л. Л.
>   Касаткин, академик РАО В. Г. Костомаров, академик МАНПО и РАЕН О. А.
>   Крылова, доктор филол. наук, профессор Л. п. Крысин, доктор филол.
>   наук С. М. Кузьмина, доктор филол. наук, профессор О. В. Кукушкина,
>   доктор филол. наук, профессор В. В. Лопатин (председатель комиссии),
>   учитель русского языка и литературы В. В. Луховицкий, зав.
>   лабораторией русского языка и литературы Московского института
>   повышения квалификации работников образования Н. А. Нефедова, канд.
>   филол. наук И. К. Сазонова, доктор филол. наук А. В. Суперанская,
>   канд. филол. наук Л. К. Чельцова, доктор филол. наук, профессор А. Д.
>   Шмелев, доктор филол. наук, профессор М. В. Шульга. Активное участие в
>   обсуждении и редактировании текста правил принимали недавно ушедшие из
>   жизни члены комиссии: доктора филол. наук, профессора В. Ф. Иванова,
>   Б. С. Шварцкопф, Е. Н. Ширяев, кандидат филол. наук Н. В. Соловьев.
>   Основной задачей этой работы была подготовка полного и отвечающего
>   современному состоянию русского языка текста правил русского
>   правописания. Действующие до сих пор «Правила русской орфографии и
>   пунктуации», официально утвержденные в 1956 г., были первым
>   общеобязательным сводом правил, ликвидировавшим разнобой в
>   правописании. Со времени их выхода прошло ровно полвека, на их основе
>   были созданы многочисленные пособия и методические разработки.
>   Естественно, что за это время в формулировках «Правил» обнаружился ряд
>   существенных пропусков и неточностей. Неполнота «Правил» 1956 г. в
>   большой степени объясняется изменениями, произошедшими в самом языке:
>   появилось много новых слов и типов слов, написание которых «Правилами»
>   не регламентировано. Например, в современном языке активизировались
>   единицы, стоящие на грани между словом и частью слова; среди них
>   появились такие, как мини, макси, видео, аудио, медиа, ретро и др. В
>   «Правилах» 1956 г. нельзя найти ответ на вопрос, писать ли такие
>   единицы слитно со следующей частью слова или через дефис. Устарели
>   многие рекомендации по употреблению прописных букв. Нуждаются в
>   уточнениях и дополнениях правила пунктуации, отражающие стилистическое
>   многообразие и динамичность современной речи, особенно в массовой
>   печати. Таким образом, подготовленный текст правил русского
>   правописания не только отражает нормы, зафиксированные в «Правилах»
>   1956 г., но и во многих случаях дополняет и уточняет их с учетом
>   современной практики письма. Регламентируя правописание, данный
>   справочник, естественно, не может охватить и исчерпать все конкретные
>   сложные случаи написания слов. В этих случаях необходимо обращаться к
>   орфографическим словарям. Наиболее полным нормативным словарем
>   является в настоящее время академический «Русский орфографический
>   словарь» (изд. 2-е, М., 2005), содержащий 180 тысяч слов. Данный
>   справочник по русскому правописанию предназначается для преподавателей
>   русского языка, редакционно-издательских работников, всех пишущих
>   по-русски.

https://www.booklot.org/authors/valgina-nina-sergeevna/book/pravila-russkoy-orfografii-i-punktuatsii-polnyiy-akademicheskiy-spravochnik/read/1/

Comment: РАЕН?! Дожили...

Comment: Почему РАЕН? Естественные науки здесь ни при чём. Федеральное государственное бюджетное учреждение «Российская академия наук», сокр. РАН — государственная академия наук Российской Федерации, крупнейший в стране центр фундаментальных исследований.

Comment: Значит, у вас опечатка. )

Comment: Нет у меня никакой опечатки. Если Вы о Крыловой, то она тоже филолог, занимается синтаксисом, а должности у неё разные: ученый секретарь Ученого совета историко-филологического факультета РУДН,зам. зав.кафедрой по работе с аспирантами, академик Международной академии наук педагогического образования (МАН ПО), академик Российской академии естественных наук (РАЕН),член Орфографической комиссии при Институте русского языка им. В.В.Виноградова РАН, член диссертационного совета  при РУДН, член диссерт. совета при Балтийском федеральном университете им. Иммануила Канта. Не все же перечислять.

Comment: Просто РАЕН – организация одиозная. Ее члены – это в основном "непризнанные гении", опровергающие "официальную науку". Поэтому я и удивился.

Comment: А может, не одиозная, а творческая, ищущая? Что-то наша официальная наука о природе, о Земле стала часто опровергаться не только учёными, но и самой жизнью, артефактами. Да и вообще наука стала близка так называемым лженаукам. Кто их разберёт, кто прав, пусть все ищут - больше пользы, чем что-то запрещать и хаять.

Comment: Вот-вот, они именно так себя и называют. ) "Официальная наука" – как только эти слова кем-то произнесены, следует насторожиться: перед вами очередная "творческая, но непонятая натура". Ибо не делится наука на официальную и неофициальную. А делится на науку и ненауку. Псевдоученые спекулируют на том, что люди часто думают: раз есть у нас (было) "официальное искусство", которое всем обрыдло до чёртиков (соцреализм), то должна быть и "официальная наука". Спекуляция не очень-то благовидная.